# React native fetch multi markers [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.markers.map

Tags: react-native

I have attempted to fetch data from Google Places (nearbysearch) API, and in this returns an object in JSON of list of locations based on the query i made. I simply want to handle these objects and take their latitude and longitude values and mark them as markers to be rendered and returned in a MapView and this is what i have done so far. (pardon for my messy code as this is my first time on attempting to do this and trying out things for the first time).

```js
export default class Whereto extends Component<{}> {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

this.state = {
    latitude: null,
    longitude: null,
    location: null,
    error: null,
    markers:[
        {latlng: {latitude: null, longitude: null}}
    ]
};
}
```

then i am using geolocation library to find my current location and use this later as a query to the nearbyplaces API

```js
componentDidMount() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
                this.setState({
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                    error: null,
                });

            var myApiKey = '';

            fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude + '&key=' + myApiKey)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    //console.log('ADDRESS GEOCODE is BACK!! => ' + JSON.stringify(responseJson));
                   .... .....
                }) this section is not the complete code but it is working which is simply used to return my current location
```

following on under my componentdidMount() function is the fetch to Google Places nearbysearch(API)

```js
var apiPlaceskey = '';
                //https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY



fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=' + position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude + '&radius=500&type=bus_station&key=' + apiPlaceskey)
                .then((respplaces) => respplaces.json())
                .then((responseJson2) => {
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(responseJson2));
                    //var locationName = responseJson.results[0].address_components.filter(x => x.types.filter(t => t === 'administrative_area_level_2').length > 0)[0].short_name;
                    for (var i = 0, length = responseJson2.length; i < length; i++){
                        var data = json[i],
                           latlng = (responseJson2.results[0].geometry.location.lat, responseJson2.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
                    }
                this.setState({
                    markers: latlng
                })
```

it seems that the API call is successful as i do get a return, and here is a sample..

```js
{
  "html_attributions": [],
  "results": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 52.90050499999999,
          "lng": -1.478267
        },
        "viewport": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 52.90185398029149,
            "lng": -1.476918019708498
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 52.89915601970849,
            "lng": -1.479615980291502
          }
        }
      },
      "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bus-71.png",
      "id": "4e992af207c8ff3503999574d25155ccf9b48f70",
      "name": "Randolph Road",
      "place_id": "ChIJM0syu93weUgRXSKhX6Flay8",
      "reference": "CmRRAAAAaE7cMbH9gq0w1U18RFtzX1GsEjTb7G2msTt4sL1hnvb5DrwTpFyznlVc9TvlfkOSkmJwU-dMa_RAvTO_8hCe_FeGIpQjwxMs7izIMg_oWYtGyzu9jQ0aIL9a_dRO40KvEhCrcpisZYRNNpDJH6p31oa6GhQpwF8PSkltIQvmsLMabEAnJWQ3OA",
      "scope": "GOOGLE",
      "types": [
        "bus_station",
        "transit_station",
        "point_of_interest",
        "establishment"
      ],
      "vicinity": "United Kingdom"
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 52.900963,
          "lng": -1.478217
        },
        "view ........
and here comes my render section.

render(){

        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Mainlogo/>

                <MapView style={styles.map}>

                    <MapView.Marker
                        coordinate={{
                            latitude: this.state.latitude,
                            longitude: this.state.longitude,
                            latitudeDelta: 0.02,
                            longitudeDelta: 0.02
                        }}
                        image={require('../img/my-pin-512.png')}
                        title={'you are here'}
                    />

                    {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
                        <MapView.Marker
                            coordinate={marker.latlng}
                        />

                    ))}

                </MapView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

After multiple tweaks and modifying and search in web i have no luck, and keeping on getting this error:

```js
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.markers.map')] 22:23:24 ▼Warning: Failed prop type: The prop coordinate.latitude is marked as required in MapMarker, but its value is null.
```

[image]

[image]

the new error

Comment: What is this doing? `latlng = (responseJson2.results[0].geometry.location.lat, responseJson2.results[0].geometry.location.lng);`

Comment: im trying to get the latitude and longitude values from the results json and have the longitude and latitude values from there as the values for my markers. i think that for loop is not returning anything.  var busstoplat = responseJson2.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                        var bustolong = responseJson2.results[0].geometry.location.lng;  having it in a variable like gets the lat and long

Comment: If you console.log latlng right before you setState, what do you get?

Comment: im getting undefined.

Comment: ok...but as you loop you're just updating data to the current item in the array, so it will always = the last item once you're done. Not sure exactly what you're trying to do but i think you need to use map instead if you're trying to adjust the response before you set it as the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do...create a new array with lat/long and set it as the markers. Replace your loop and setState with this:

```js
const markers = responseJson2.results.map((result) => ({
  latlng: {
    latitude: result.geometry.location.lat,
    longitude: result.geometry.location.lng,
  }
});

this.setState({ markers });
```

Comment: hi yes. spot on exactly what i am trying to do. the reason i thought i needed a for loop is because i thought i needed to iterate within the json

Comment: It seems now that i am getting this error : Error while updating property coordinate of a view managed by: AIRMapMarker , i added the screenshot if this above

Comment: I think it's because you have an item in there as default with null values. try having markers default to an empty array in your state.

Answer (score 0):

at first glance this looks like an async issue.

Your `render` method has no check against undefined values. 
Here is the part I'm talking about:

```js
{this.state.markers.map(marker => (
  // ...
))}
```

The render method is going to be called before your fetch request has the results. However `this.state.markers` won't be populated by that time.

You should add some sort of placeholder view, that can be displayed before the results from the google api return.

Something like this:

```js
render() {
  if (myContrivedCondition) return <View styles={styles.placeholder}/>;

  // your render code
}
```

Once the response arrived it will trigger a component update due to your `this.setState`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: myContrivedcondition?  you mean i should handle the error? if (undefined) ?

Comment: Nah, I meant, it should probably show something like a placeholder before the response comes back. Your render method is trying to access a state that is not set yet within the render method.